# How would I go about installing Gnome 2.x?

Tags: installation, gnome, 11.10, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

I am trying to weigh out the pros and cons of upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10 from 11.04. I am currently using Gnome for my desktop environment. How would I go about installing Gnome 2.x to Ubuntu 11.10?

I haven't upgraded yet, I am just trying to gather information about the upgrading and issues I may run into before I upgrade.

Thanks!

Comment: are you just interested in using something similar to the old interface as per this AU Question?: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks! :)